# PlayFramework 2.5.3 project creation error in Intellij IDEA 15

Tags: playframework-2.5, intellij-scala

I have configured Scala 2.11.7 version in the IntelliJ Idea settings.
I have created a new play framework project in IntelliJ Idea 15.
Once the project is created successfully, I have opened the controller file "Application.scala" and found compilation errors.

The error says it couldn't resolve the symbol. It is not able to find the package play.api._

The play framework version is 2.5.3

I have attached below the error screenshot.

[image]

Do I need any other configuration for play framework in IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 1):

First try updating the Scala plugin if its not updated

If that does not work you can try re-importing the project;

During the import process first screen select "Import from external model" and select "SBT" then on second screen there should be "Use auto-import" checkbox and click Finish. This should configure IntelliJ to automatically import all dependencies.

Wait for 2 process running [ Shown in IntelliJ status bar at the bottom ] and also wait for indexing to complete [ statusbar ].

After that it should be able to resolve the dependencies.